# compile time vs runtime recursion

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

Is template recursion more efficient than non-template recursion?

I.e. which one of the two is better:

```
typedef std::vector<int> Ivec;
template <int N>
void test1(Ivec& v){
    assert(v.size() >= N);
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){v[i]++;}
    test1<N-1>(v);
}
template <>
void test1<0>(Ivec& v){}


void test2(Ivec& v,int N){
    assert(v.size() >= N);
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){v[i]++;}
    if (N == 1) {return;}
    test2(v,N-1);
}
```

Comment: They should be fairly similar in performance since v is unknown at compile time, and the first version will generate N versions of test1 functions which will result in bigger generated file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be surprised if the template version is ever slower. It should be faster most of the time, if not every time. After all, the template version computes the values at compile time.

Here's program that times the two approaches.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cassert>

typedef std::vector<int> Ivec;

template <int N>
void test1(Ivec& v){
   assert(v.size() >= N);
   for (int i=0;i<N;i++){v[i]++;}
   test1<N-1>(v);
}

template <>
void test1<0>(Ivec& v){}

void test2(Ivec& v,int N){
   assert(v.size() >= N);
   for (int i=0;i<N;i++){v[i]++;}
   if (N == 1) {return;}
   test2(v,N-1);
}

void timeFunction(void (*fun)())
{
   clock_t start = std::clock();
   fun();
   clock_t end = std::clock();
   double secs = 1.0*(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   std::cout << "Time taken: " << secs << std::endl;
}

void time_test1()
{
   Ivec a;
   const int N = 500;
   for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i )
   {
      a.push_back(std::rand());
   }

   for ( int i = 0; i < N*20; ++i )
   {
      test1<N>(a);
   }
}

void time_test2()
{
   Ivec a;
   const int N = 500;
   for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i )
   {
      a.push_back(std::rand());
   }

   for ( int i = 0; i < N*20; ++i )
   {
      test2(a, N);
   }
}


int main()
{
   std::srand(time(NULL));
   timeFunction(time_test1);
   timeFunction(time_test2);
   return 0;
}
```

Program built on a Linux machine with g++ version 4.8.4 with the command:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11     socc.cc   -o socc
```

Output:

```
Time taken: 3.96467
Time taken: 4.32788
```

The output validates my hunch. As usual, your mileage may vary.

Comment: what values are computed at compile time? `v[i]++` could as well be `v[i] = foo(v[i])`. This cant be computed at compile time. I measured it and the template version seems to be slightly faster, but I dont really understand why

Comment: @tobi303, not all values are computed at compile time but some are. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Template recursion should be faster, but you need to know N at compile time.

Which is better?

Usually function recursion since it is more flexible and generates the machine code only once.

But if you know N at compile time ( as a define for example ) and not as something you read from a file, and the performance need is greater than the size of the generated code, than you could yake advantage of the optimisations that the compiler can do.

Comment: In this case I don't think there are much optimizations can be done.

Comment: Loop unroll and inline functions. If you are desperate for runtime, it might help. Otherwise I would stay away from this.